# Android : How can I save drag n drop coordinates to a file

Tags: android

When a user drags the image on the screen, I want to save the coordinates he dragged to a file, so that I can "playback" the movements.

If user moves a ball from top to bottom of the screen, I want to save that to a file, then on demand, read the coordinates and show the ball moving by it self, like recording the movement.

I hope this is clearer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "save"? Do you mean just retain the X,Y co-ordinates in memory as long as the Activity is alive, or do you need to persistently store the data for future use? If you need to store those co-ordinates persistently, use SQLite.

Edit: Just noticed you've said 'to a file' in the title, so yes, SQLite is the best option. Or, do you have a specific need for the data to be written to a file, as opposed to SQLite?

Your question is far too vague.

Comment: I apologize for the being vague.

Comment: I am trying to do the following:

Comment: as a user drags an imge, I will store the coordinates and then play them back. It is for a training app I am building. The user will move a ball around the field and I will save those coordinates and replay the drill.

Comment: OK. If the data doesn't need to be kept after the application has been closed, then you could simply store the coordinates inside arrays that are members of the Activity. If you need to store the data for future retrieval by that application (and only by that application) then you can store and retrieve the arrays of coordinates to/from a SQLite database.

Comment: That makes sense..I will store it in the DB as I need to keep it saved.
Let me try that

Comment: Cool, hope it works out! Don't forget to accept the answer if it has solved the issue.